# RanToCompletion when still awaiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I need to write a method that would asynchronously load and parse multiple websites.
Here is a simplified code of my approach.

```
using (HTMLParser parser = new HTMLParser(proxy))
{
    var tasks = totalSites.Select( s =>
    {
        return new Task( async () =>
        {
            s.Entity = await parser.GetSiteDataAsync(s.Entity).ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
    }).ToArray();
    foreach (var task in tasks)
        task.Start();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

`HTMLParser` class uses `HttpClient` to load sites and disposes it on dispose. Full code also uses `CancellationToken` to cancel and `SemaphoreSlim` to reduce degree of parallelism.

Problem is that when task begins awaiting for parsed data it's status is set to `RanToCompletion`. Then program passes `Task.WhenAll` and disposes `HTMLParser` causing `OperationCanceledException`s in `HttpClient`.

Comment: If your code is going to be I/O bound, your approach should *generally* not be creating new `Task` objects explicitly. I think your current code is ending up with `Task`s wrapping other `Task`s, which isn't grand.

Comment: @GWigWam , sorry, I've missed it simplifying my code. `s` is used to create `vm`.
@Damien_The_Unbeliever I think you are right: I need to create multiple tasks to load multiple websites it parallel.

Comment: @AndreyAlonzov - but for I/O bound work, you *shouldn't* be creating `Task`s - you should be leveraging `async` and `await` but the only `Task`s you should be dealing with are the ones that are *returned* by `async` methods.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If I will use that tasks how can I load, say, 40 websites at one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, you shouldn't be explicitly creating `Task`s. What I think you need is something along the lines of:

```
using (HTMLParser parser = new HTMLParser(proxy))
{
    var tasks = totalSites.Select( s => populateEntity(s)).ToArray();
    /* returned tasks are already hot */
    //foreach (var task in tasks)
    //    task.Start();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

And then separately:

```
public async Task<WhateverSIs> populateEntity(WhateverSIs s)
{
    s.Entity = await parser.GetSiteDataAsync(s.Entity).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return s;
}
```

We don't create any `Tasks` explicitly - we just use the ones exposes by `async` methods, including `GetSiteDataAsync`.

Comment: Thanks! Just did the same thing by myself. Yesterday I tried this approach but I wrote all the logic inside lambda and cancellation didn't work and forced me to create task explicitly.

Comment: @AndreyAlonzov - the problem with async lambdas is that they can easily produce either `Func` or `Action` delegates - and the `Action` ones are effectively `async void`. And if you look at [where you were passing your lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.task(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that it could only take an `Action` - so you had no way to track the progress of your lambda.